# Sending Arabic characters to Google Sheet

Tags: http, google-sheets-api

I am sending an http request to a google sheet trying to add a row of data which has some arabic characters. It works fine when using english characters but gets an empty cell when using arabic characters. You can use the following post request in any language.

```
params.body = "pphrase=عربی‌"

network.request( "https://script.google.com/macros/s/111222334445555/exec","POST",getFeatured,params)
```

My google sheet script code which receives the request and saves the abpve params.body to a row under pphrase column:

```
// Usage
//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app 
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version' 
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously) 
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action 
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    //MailApp.sendEmail("m.hawksey@gmail.com", "data", JSON.stringify(e.parameters));
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up converting the Arabic characters to a string of numbers and send the numbers to google sheet and when getting them back convert back to Arabic.

```
local letters = {"ا","ب", "پ", "ت", "ث", "ج", "چ", "ح", "خ", "د", "ذ", "ر", "ز", "ژ", "س", "ش", "ص", "ض","ط", "ظ", "ع", "غ", "ف", "ق", "ک", "گ", "ل", "م", "ن", "و", "ه", "ی", "\b"}
function returnIndex( a )
  for j=1,33 do
    if a==letters[j] then
      print(j)
      jokeText=j.." "..jokeText
    end
  end
end

       local joke = "عربی‌"

        for i = 1, #joke+1 do
          print(string.sub(joke, i, i+1))
            returnIndex(string.sub(joke, i, i+1))
        end
```